# How to change every second elements of array in c using for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm using a for loop to create an 100 element array of char. I on the first run, I want to change all of its values to 1, the second run, I want its every second values to 0

```
char array[ 100 ] = { 0 };

int toggle_swith(char a[]) {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf(array[i] + "1 ");
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf(array[i] + "0 ");
        toggle_switch();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `array[i,1-3]` supposed to be?

Comment: Actually, what's *any* of this code have to do with the question? None of it can possibly work.

Comment: I changed it to what it's supposed to be. I was playing with it for a little

Comment: Also, those `printf(array[i] + "0 ")` lines look terribly wrong. Grab a beginner C tutorial, this is not how this language works.

Comment: I know, for now, I just want the switches to work then i'll work on formatting

Comment: It's much more useful to post actual code you're building.

Comment: This code will print an array of 100 elements each initialized to zero. The method toggle_switch will change these 0 values to 1. I need another method that is able to switch every other second values to 1

Comment: First read this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info, try to get ==> The C Programming Language (Second edition) - Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function which initializes the array:

```
void InitializeArray(char Array[], int Length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
    Array[i] = '1';
  }
}
```

You need a function which changes every 2nd element:

```
void ChangeEverySecondElement(char Array[], int Length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <  Length; i += 2) {
    Array[i] = '0';
  }
}
```

You need a function to print the array :

```
void PrintArray(char Array[], int Length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
    putchar(Array[i]);
    putchar(' ');
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Then you need to put them together

```
int main() {
  char Array[100];
  InitializeArray(Array, 100);
  PrintArray(Array, 100);
  ChangeEverySecondElement(Array, 100);
  PrintArray(Array, 100);
  return 0;
}
```

If you are trying to learn C, I recommend the book I learned it from, *C by Example* written by Greg Perry.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very interested in C, I will look up all these books and see which one I like better. I have experience in java but c is very interesting

Comment: Just a note, This will make array elements as '0' and '1', not 0 and 1. '0' != 0. If you want 0, then remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it all at once

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) array[i]=(i%2)+'0';
```

a typical attempt at optimization could look like:

```
#define BUFSZ 100
int main(){
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    int *bp=(int *)&buf, i=(BUFSZ/sizeof(int));
     /* handle aligned words 4 bytes at a time */
    while (i) bp[--i]='0101'; /* for 64 bit use '0101'|('0101' <<32) */
     /* handle unaligned bytes */
    for(i=(BUFSZ/sizeof(int))*sizeof(int);i<BUFSZ;i++)buf[i]=1-i%2+'0';
    write(1,buf,BUFSZ);
}
```

Comment: well its not 100% optimized, i%2 would probably get optimized to i&1 by a decent compiler though, or you could cast to an array of int and initialize 32/64 bits at a time ... also I wasn't clear whether it should be 01010101 or 10101010 ... so it might need 1-i%2+'0'

Answer (score 1):

Initially you want to make all your array elements as 1
You can use `memset`

```
memset(array,1,100)
```

This will clear all elements. But if you insist on using a loop then,

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100
char array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

for(int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
{
   array[count] = 1;
   //If you want to print it, use:
   printf("%d",array[count]; // You can also use %c
}
```

To make alternate element 0,

```
for(int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; (count = count + 2)) //Count + 2 will hop every alternate element
{
     array[count] = 0;
}
```

Again, You can add printf() if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Print statement should look something like this.

printf("%c0",array[i]);

I suggest you look up Beginner C tutorial for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up. I mainly program in java, so I don't know much about c